# Joomla 2.5 admin page 404

Tags: joomla2.5

Web site functioned normally , I tried to login to admin page and suddenly when I access admin page it display:

404 - An error has occurred.

Component not found

No new extension/module/component and theme has been installed.
No changes on PHP or mysql on the server side. ( I did check with hosting providers).

It's like it works today and tomorrow when you want to login , you'll see the above mentioned error.

Renaming .htaccess did not solve the issue. 
Restoring DB backup did not solve the issue.

I checked the Joomla logs ( in log folder) there isn't any related report.

Joomla version info:

```
$RELEASE = '2.5';
$DEV_LEVEL = '16';
```

Please help!

Comment: Look at your raw server logs, what errors are you getting when you access the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sloved this long time ago but I forgot to update!

It is solved by running repair and optimize operations on the database via phpmyadmin.